# ADC Module Recomendation?

Tags: adc

I am supposed to measure a battery's voltage, current and temperature for a project. And for this purpose i am finding an ADC module which can give me 12bits of resolution. However it should be having differential inputs, as i will be measuring the battery's voltage differentially (not referenced to ground), but the current and temperature would be measured single endedly . This ADC will be interfaced with Arduino (Leonardo most probably) to process the measured quantities. Also i want this ADC to have an external reference Voltage allowable so that i might provide it with an accurate reference voltage with some IC like MAX6161 (from maxim). I have visited companies websites, and tried to find ADC with my requirements, but i couldn't so far. Also i find some ADC's to be pseudo differential rather than just differential, and i read online about their difference, and i think differential would be needed in my case.  Can anyone please help me in this regard ?

So what i want in my ADC are the following :

1) At least 12 bit of resolution

2) 4 channel input (differential)

3) External reference voltage allowable

4) SPI interface (to microcontroller) (as ive read online that SPI is better than I2C in terms of noise senstivity if only one slave is to be connected with Master, which is my case)

5) A very good accuracy, i.e very low INL(<=1LSB), DNL(<=1LSB), Offset(<=4LSB) and Gain error(<=4LSB).

Thankyou.

B = Battery

C.S = Current Source

Xu = Voltage measured

Xi = Current measured

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need a differential ADC to measure battery voltage? It seems to me that what you're trying to do could be done with just about any plain vanilla ADC with the proper signal conditioning.

Comment: For you answer i added a rough image of how i am planning to measure the battery's voltage and current. I will be using low side current measurement technique, so it could be done single endedly as one terminal of shunt resistor (out of the two) is at ground. However if you can see in the above image, for voltage measurement, i HAVE TO do it differentially as you can see that the negative terminal of the battery is not grounded directly, it has a current shunt in its path for the current measurement. Thats what i have thought so far, i hope i am thinking right. Am i ?

Comment: That is irrelevant. Your shunt resistor should be dropping a few mV. Further, why are you doing low side current sensing? 12 bit resolution is insane for measuring battery voltage, especially if you're trying to infer capacity.

Comment: Yes you are right, shunt resistor would be dropping a few milli volts, that is why i cannot measure my battery's voltage wrt ground, as there is a voltage drop(of shunt resistance) in between battery cell and the ground, so i am planning to measure it via differential adc. Low side im using as according to all the articles ive read online, its easy to implement (amplifier required in that case wont be needing a large rail to rail voltage range) also it can be measured single endedly when done on the low side (as one side of the shunt is gorund).

Comment: Also 12bit adc is required as im supposed to measure these quantities very very accurately, near in the range of 0.1%-0.5% accuracy. However by reading your questions i have started to feel that im trying to do somthing stupid here, am i ? as this is gonna be my first experience in hardware work, as ive never done anything like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the Leonardo ([ATmega32U4](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf)) itself and see how it can get what you need.

> 1) At least 12 bit of resolution

This sounds like a no-go right on the first step, seeing as how the ADC in the ATmega32U4 only supports 10 bits of resolution. But the thing to remember is that this is at a rate of 15kS/s. If you don't need that rate (which is highly unlikely for battery monitoring) then you can perform [oversampling and decimation](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8003.pdf) in order to increase not only the resolution but also the *accuracy* of the built-in ADC.

> 2) 4 channel input (differential)

12 channels, with differential *plus gain* on two of them. Check.

> 3) External reference voltage allowable

Yeeees, but... you may find yourself not needing it. The built-in 2.56V reference may be accurate enough for your needs, but obviously you would have to determine this empirically.

> 4) SPI interface (to microcontroller) (as ive read online that SPI is better than I2C in terms of noise senstivity if only one slave is to be connected with Master, which is my case)

All AVR MCU peripherals have a parallel interface to the core.

> 5) A very good accuracy, i.e very low INL(<=1LSB), DNL(<=1LSB), Offset(<=4LSB) and Gain error(<=4LSB).

The typical values for the ADC are certainly within those values, and both [characterization and calibration](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2559.pdf) and oversampling and decimation can help iron them out even flatter.

Comment: Thats exactly what i first had in my mind,i.e to use its internal ADC as i didnt want to do extra work by interfacing an external ADC to the UC.But when i went through its data sheet, i found out that its ADC's resolution drops if you use it as a diff i/p ADC, as you can see on pg 276 para#2 : *If 1x, 10x, or 40x gain is used, 8-bit resolution can be expected* . I dont know why is it so, but sadly it is. So i think i wil have to use an external ADC after all. And the reason i am trying to measure voltage differentially is explained in the above post comments, i also added a pic to support that

Comment: So any recommendation from your side ?